# Communcation with wordrpess and linux server

Tags: linux

Is there any way to send & receive data between Wordpress & linux server ?
What i wants to do is

- Take data from user from wordpress page
- Send data to linux server for processing
- Once data is processed on linux server receive it on Wordpress page where user has entered data and show results

I know socket programming but i couldn't find enough resource about socket programming between WP and linux.

is there any way to achive this ?

Comment: Sure, write a php extension that communicate via a pipe or socket or whatever. Maybe such one even exists. Is it smart to do such a thing? probably not. downvoting and close voting as I do not see what exactly is wordpress specific in this question and it is too broad.

Comment: i already tried google but couldn't find any resource to achieve this

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Comment: I knows that but what about authentication(username & password) ?

Comment: what about it, and how is it specific to wordpress? (and... I said right above I am not sure it is a smart thing to do)

Comment: i mean "how do i connect WP with a linux sever where Linux server has username and password for connection" using sockets ?

Comment: same as you connect every other php application

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php where do i write username and password in this ?

Answer (score 1):

Its just PHP dude, if you want to do this, just google it.

But, why do you want to do this? Can you be more specific? Because, PHP can retrieve this data, but depending on what you want to do, you'll have to use some JS to show this data, retrieve with PHP and show with JS.

Like, You want to answer some input with some data? I can imagine like 10000 ways to do this..

Comment: can you suggest me few resources or examples ?

Comment: Like, what do you want to do with this?

Comment: apply various algorithm on user data

Comment: I see, just use PHP, it'll work